# How long do geostrophic currents last?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, estimation, geophysics, oceanography

My professor posed this question, without any relevant material. I suppose the currents last until the density gradient is neutralized, but I can't find any literature nor articles on this, regarding the time scale. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE].  If you don't get a good answer here (as I suspect you might not without providing more context), you might consider asking this same question over at [Earthscience.SE];  it's probably a better fit for a question like this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I suspected that this forum is more active than Earth Science, but here goes nothing. Regretably, that is all the context there is to this question.